# AngularJS $http.post server doesn't allow a request with method OPTIONS

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I am trying to do a an HTTP POST to a server.

The data I have to send is a json object.

The problem is that $http.post in angular override the method with options.

I can make this config

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
  //Reset headers to avoid OPTIONS request (aka preflight)
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
}])
```

and changes from options to POST, but I can't set the content-type to "application/json", and I am getting a "415 Unsupported Media Type"

Thank you

Comment: Do you have control of the server you are accessing? It might not support an OPTIONS method request. You can't avoid preflight when using CORS via $httpProvider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$http.post in angular doesn't override the method with OPTIONS. It appear that you are trying to call api in different domain than the one your JS code come from. This is called Cross Domain. For such cases the browser performs preflight request with OPTIONS in order to see the returned headers. In your backend response you should add the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` for example. When the browser sees that header he performs the actual POST request.

More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Hope this is helps!

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what it is happening, but I already have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in the server, and I get the same error.

Comment: @agusgambina: Open devtools in chrome, which exception exactly do you get in console?

Comment: The server doesn't allow CORS, so I am looking for which options I have available, one is to implement a proxy to make the requests. Thanks for the answers @Naor.

Comment: @Naor how do you provide a backend response that allows the cross-domain ?

Comment: @Naor I am POSTing to a POST route set up on Sinatra running on heroku

Comment: @Angela I don't know. I can help you with node's express.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
```

**But note this will set the Content-Type header globally.**

If you need to set the content-type per call, you should use `$http.post` like

```
 $http.post("/foo/bar", requestData, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        transformRequest: transform
    }).success(function(responseData) {
        //do stuff with response
    });
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I tried both, put it globally and local in the function, but the same result, change the request method to options.

Comment: Shouldn't have to do this, the default for $http.post is application/json. See /docs/api/ng/service/$http for your version, search for 'Setting HTTP Headers'.

Comment: this actually worked for me.
had to use 

`$http.post(url, data)` 

instead of 

`$http({ method: 'POST', data: data })`